# Semantic UI Form Match Validation Not Working

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

```
// Register form validation
  $('.register-form')
  .form({
    on: 'blur',
    fields: {
      registerEmail: {
        identifier  : 'registerEmail',
        rules: [{
            type   : 'email',
            prompt : 'Please enter a valid email address.'
        }]
      },
      registerPassword: {
        identifier  : 'registerPassword',
        rules: [{
            type   : 'empty',
            prompt : 'Please enter a password.'
        }]
      },
      registerPasswordVerify: {
        identifier  : 'registerPasswordVerify',
        rules: [{
            type   : 'match[registerPassword]',
            prompt : 'Your passwords do not match.'
        }]
      }
    },
    onSuccess: function() {
      $scope.createUser();
      console.log("Passed");
    },
    onFailure: function() {
      console.log("Failed");
    }
  });
```

Not sure what is wrong here exactly, but I'm simply trying to get the two password fields to match but I keep getting the "Your passwords do not match" error.  Here's my HTML as well:

```
<div class="field">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="registerPassword" ng-model="password">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Verify Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="registerPasswordVerify">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. After trying few options, i realize that `registerPassword` inside `match[registerPassword]` is undefined. `match` is not looking for name of the input, but the `id` of the input.
So if you put `id="registerPassword"` in your password input. That should work. I don't know why this is not in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this. It is indeed really weird that it's not in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

you will working just add id name of every input

Password

```
  <div class="field">
    <label>Verify Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="registerPasswordVerify"  id="registerPassword">
  </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the other answer given more than a year ago,  but without the explanation.